# Plot as many circles as histogram values under the histogram line

Tags: svg, d3.js

as the title suggests I am trying to visualize the value of the histogram bins using circles under the line itself. To achieve this I thought that the best option vould be to use a dotted line, but as of now I am not that sure. The problem I am having is, since this histogram is interactive, the bins can be changed so the circles should scale accordingly.
What I have so far is accessible here:
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37967455/confronto_pesi.html
(please check the sans box and use that line as reference) 
As you can see, using the slider sometimes returns the correct amount of dots and sometimes doesn't.
 My guess is that it could be related to the width and spacing of the dots.

The part used to build the dotted lines is like so (I used two lines to fake the circles):

```
var dline1 = svg.append("g")
                .attr("id", "dline1");
dline1.selectAll("line")
                .data(histogSans)
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .attr("x1", function (d, i) { return x(histogSans[i].x); })
                .attr("x2", function (d, i) { return x(histogSans[i].x); })
                .attr("y1", y(1))
                .attr("y2", function (d, i) { return y(histogSans[i].y); })
                .attr("stroke", "#386cb0")
                .attr("stroke-width", 4)
                .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
                .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0, " + parseFloat(y(32.75)) + "");
var dline2 = svg.append("g")
                .attr("id", "dline2");
dline2.selectAll("line")
                .data(histogSans)
                .enter()
                .append("line")
                .attr("x1", function (d, i) { return x(histogSans[i].x); })
                .attr("x2", function (d, i) { return x(histogSans[i].x); })
                .attr("y1", y(1))
                .attr("y2", function (d, i) { return y(histogSans[i].y); })
                .attr("stroke", "white")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
                .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0, " + parseFloat(y(32.75)) + "");
```

Can it be done in an easier way, maybe using circles instead? What I was not sure using circles was how to put them in the right place and right number, like the dotted line I'm trying to do. 
Any help would be great, thanks!

EDIT: Sorry didn't realize that this (kind of) worked in safari but not on chrome, what I am trying to get is:
[image]
but that the circles get updated with the slider also and show the correct number of circles matching the histogram value

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Something like a [beeswarm plot](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/~eklund/beeswarm/)?

Comment: no, the result I'm getting without changing the histogram bins is what I want to achieve. The circles should show how many entries are in that bin, so the way they are now is ok

Comment: what I mean is, if the value of the point of the histogram says 130 there should be 130 circles under the line, this doesn't happen right now and that's what I'm not able to fix, maybe using circles instead of the dotted line will resolve the problem

Comment: How do you want those circles to appear? Just a line of circles?

Comment: Like the example with the line, I'd like to have the numbers of circles related to that bin working with the rescaling of the bin number

Comment: added an image, didn't think that it was not working properly on chrome

Comment: That should be fairly easy -- it's an example of a nested selection. The only twist is that you'd want a range from 1 to the value for the number of circles. It would be helpful if you could provide a jsfiddle or something like that.

Comment: I've set up a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/snbBx/ but I don't know why it won't load the external csv, I put it in external resources, the link to the csv itself is here: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37967455/typeStatsTom.csv

Comment: Not sure what's going on with the CSV, but the code to add the circles with a nested selection would be something like http://jsfiddle.net/snbBx/2/ (starting line 135).

Comment: the circles generated in each group return NaN as cx, I tried using i, histogSans[i].x but nothing worked. Also using a value in pixel doesn't show any of the circles, I'm pretty clueless on how to solve this. I think it was also missing a .enter() after the second .data.
I've updated it a bit, I think it's close to the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/snbBx/4/

Comment: That still doesn't work for me because of some issues with loading the CSV. http://plnkr.co/ might be better for something with files.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/03qJT9R2sq1i4AdIil1t?p=preview this should work, I tried it on both Safari and Chrome and shows the graph

Comment: Is http://plnkr.co/edit/W1Ijveq5GdVDkI9XIXL4?p=preview what you're looking for? I've put in only the code to add the circles, but updating them should be fairly straightforward from that.

Comment: Yes, it is thank you very much! if you want to, put the code in an answer so I can mark it as correct! thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is basically a [nested selection](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) -- for each bin, add the circles representing the values. The only difficulty in your case is that the property that determines the x position is only available in the parent and not the nesting. This is easily fixed by copying that value.

The relevant code is below.

```
SansCircleGroup.selectAll("g.circle")
    .data(histogSans)
    .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "circle")
            .each(function(d) { d.forEach(function(e) { e.x = d.x; }); })
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(function (d) { return d; })
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d, i) { return x(d.x); })
            .attr("cy", function (d, i) { return y(i+1); })
            .attr("r", 2)
            .style("fill", "white")
            .style("stroke", "#386cb0")
            .style("stroke-width", 1);
```

Complete example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/W1Ijveq5GdVDkI9XIXL4?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

"What I was not sure using circles was how to put them in the right place and right number, like the dotted line I'm trying to do."

Circles can be designated an x position which will correspond to that same value as your histogram bars.

```
dline2.selectAll("circle")
  .data(histogSans)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr({
    "cx": function (d, i) { return x(histogSans[i].x); }, 
    "cy": function (d, i) { return height + 10px}, // ie. some constant just below your bars
    "r": 5px
  });
```

The dataset will determine the number of circles (var numCircles = histogSans.length), which satisfies the quantity.

Comment: in fact histogSans[i].x returns the same result as d.x

Comment: You can however, position the circle lower in the svg window by setting up "cy" accordingly.  The appear above/below you can set cy to whatever you desire.

Comment: yes but that is not automated and would require a lot of code to be made, also if the bins are changed with the slider it would be a pain to reset each cy of each circle

Comment: Making cy a function of i would work here, since i is incremented and should map the circles to a unique pixel-space.  ie. "cy": function (d,i) { return (height + i); }, slap a multiple on 1 to space them out as needed?